# for loop to while conversion

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Here I have a C++ code with for loops.

```
for(int A=1;A<=3;A++)
    {
     cout<<A*2;
     for(int B=1;B<=A;B++)
     cout<<"*";
     cout<<endl;
    }
```

and it gives me this output.

2*
4**
6***

I need to do the same thing using while loops. so I convert the above code to this one.

```
while(A<=3)
    {
    cout<<A*2;
        while(A>=B)
        {cout<<"*";
            B++;}

    cout<<endl;
    A++;
    }
```

but this code give me the output 
2*
4*
6*

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong there in my while loop.

Comment: You're missing the initialization of A and B

Comment: And after the second while you should reset B

Answer (score 3):

```
int A = 1;
int B;

while (A <= 3)
{
    cout << A * 2;
    B = 1;
    while (B <= A)
    {
        cout.put('*');
        ++B;
    }

    cout.put('\n');
    ++A;
}
```

### ioccc-style:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int A{1};while(!(A>>2)&&std::cout.put((A<<1)|0x30)){
        int B{A++};while(std::cout.put((!B)["*\n"]),B--);}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not giving A or B initial values.

```
void func()
{
    int A = 1;
    while (A<=3)
    {
        std::cout << A*2;
        int B = 1;
        while(A>=B)
        {
            std::cout << "*";
            B++;
        }

        std::cout<<endl;
        A++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I only have copied the while loop. and I declared A and B outside the outer while loop like @sombrero said.
But i get the wrong out put. and When I declared the B within outer while loop like you guys suggest it works fine. Thank you everyone you helped me there.

but however why it doesn't work when I declared the B outside the outer while loop?

Comment: @KLM of course you can **declare** B outside any loop but you have to reset it to `1` before entering the inner loop.

Comment: @Swordfish
Thank you for the information. I'm still a beginner to the C++. this really helped me to fix the code and understand the code well.

Comment: @KLM this is not a C++ issue, this is about learning how to program. In any programming language You would have the same problem.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk actually I'm a beginner to programming too.
Thank you for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Your second snippet doesn't show where you declared `A` or `B`. I'm assuming it's outside of the outer while loop which won't work. You have to declare `B` inside the first while or reinitialize it every loop.

```
int A = 1;
while(A <= 3)
{
  cout << A * 2;
  int B = 1;
  while(A >= B)
  {
    cout << "*";
    ++B;
  }
  ++A;
  cout << endl;
}
```

[Result](https://ideone.com/CnfMZk).

Comment: @Swordfish Beat you to it.

Comment: Matter of seconds. You're still missing the newline, though ;-P

Comment: @Swordfish Fair enough :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use B as local variable, alson change the `while` comparation to less and equal.

```
int A = 1;

while(A<=3) {
    cout<<A*2;
    int B = 1; // B as local variable
    while(B<=A) {
        cout<<"*";
        B++;
    }
    cout<<endl;
    A++;
}
```

**Output:**

2*
4**
6***

Answer (score 0):

```
int A = 1;
while(A <= 3)
{
    cout<<A*2;
    int B = 1;
    while(A >= B){
        cout<<"*";
        B++;
    }
    cout<<"/n";
    A++;
}
```

output :
2*
4**
6***