# Traverse a doubly Linked List to a given index

Tags: c++

I'm working on a doubly linked list and want to implement an insert() function at a given index. Right now I am able to traverse through the linked list with a for loop. However, I want execute the traversing with a while loop but I cant figure it out.

The for loop I am running is

```
   for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++) {
           //move the temp pointer down the list 
           temp = temp->next; 
       }
```

The full insert() function:

```
template<typename Data>
void Link<Data>::insert(int index, Data value) {

    if (head == nullptr) {
        Link<Data>::push2Front(value);
    }
    else if (index >= size) {
        Link<Data>::add2Rear(value);
    }
    else {
        Node* temp = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++) {
            temp = temp->next; 
        } 
        Node* nn = new Node;
        nn->value = value; 
        nn->next = temp->next;
        nn->prev = temp->prev;
        temp->next->prev = nn;
        temp->next = nn;
        size++;
    }
}
```

Suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: You're not checking to see if next is a null value. Search for "c++ convert for loop to while loop"

Comment: whats the problem with the `while` loop? `while( i < index - 1) {  .... ; i++; }`

Comment: Linked lists shouldn’t be indexed.

Comment: *"I want execute the traversing with a while loop"* -- why? What benefit do you hope to gain?

Comment: Why wouldn't `nn->prev = temp;` if you are inserting `nn` after `temp`? Take out a piece of paper and a pencil. Draw out the `temp` and `temp->next` nodes with the pointers drawn as lines with arrows between them. Now break the pointer lines with the eraser and draw `nn` above and between the two node. Now draw in what the new pointer connections need to be -- then write your code to make that happen.

Comment: @JaMiT knowledge.

Comment: @ouet.hands In the pursuit of knowledge, there are many resources to read, such as [how to convert an for loop to while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47611375/),  [for loop to while conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52236270/), [for loop converted to a while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795898/), and of course [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for), which describes what a `for` loop does in terms of an equivalent `while` loop.

Comment: @JaMiT Thanks! I'll check those out.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
int i=0;

while(i<index-1){

  temp=temp->next;
  ++i;

}
```

Comment: That is unsafe. There is no `nullptr` check.

Comment: It could be safe, if you knew with 100% certainty that first `index` pointers are non-NULL (i.e. if you are keeping a list-length field separately and you validate that `index` is smaller than that beforehand)

Answer (score 0):

Using a `while` loop instead is very easy, just decrement `index` until it reaches 0, eg:

```cpp
template<typename Data>
void Link<Data>::insert(int index, Data value) {
    if (index <= 0) {
        Link<Data>::push2Front(value);
    }
    else if (index >= count) {
        Link<Data>::add2Rear(value);
    }
    else {
        Node* temp = head;
        while (--index > 0) {
            temp = temp->next; 
        } 
        Node* nn = new Node;
        nn->value = value; 
        nn->next = temp->next;
        nn->prev = temp;
        if (temp->next) temp->next->prev = nn;
        temp->next = nn;
        ++size;
    }
}
```

That being said, the `insert()` code can be simplified a bit further:

```cpp
template<typename Data>
void Link<Data>::insert(int index, Data value) {
    if (index < 0 || index > size) {
        throw std::out_of_range("");
    }
    Node** temp = &head;
    Node* prev = nullptr;
    while (index-- > 0) {
        prev = *temp;
        temp = &(prev->next);
    }    
    Node* nn = new Node;
    nn->value = value; 
    nn->next = *temp;
    nn->prev = prev;
    if (*temp) (*temp)->prev = nn;
    *temp = nn;
    ++size;
}
```